# Is there a bug in node.js pathToFileURL()/fileURLToPath()?

Tags: node.js, windows, ntfs, unc

I tried the following unit tests:

```
test('nodejs URL pathToFileURL() works', () => {
    let dosPath = '\\\\?\\UNC\\diskstation\\home\\cpan-modules.txt'
    let theUrl = pathToFileURL(dosPath);
    let thePath = fileURLToPath(theUrl);
})
;
```

And it failed with the following exception:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_FILE_URL_PATH]: File URL path must be absolute
    at getPathFromURLWin32 (internal/url.js:1310:13)
    at Object.fileURLToPath (internal/url.js:1342:22)
    at Context.<anonymous> (c:\<anonymized>\out\test\suite\extension.test.js:85:29)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

The file exists and can be read:

[image: image showing the command <code>type \\?\UNC\diskstation\home\cpan-modules.txt</code>]

Note that the documentation says that `pathToFileURL()` will make the path `absolute`. This makes the complaint from `fileUrlToPath()` about the path not being absolute quite strange.

- https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathtofileurl_path
- https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_fileurltopath_url

I am developping a VS-Code extension using VS-Code 1.43.1

[image: image showing VS-Code version]

Comment: nope, I stopped my VS code extensions development at this point and focused on other projects :)